# How can I make an OData endpoint based on a Dynamic EDM that does not break the Attribute Routing Convention?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dynamic, odata

I am attempting to create a set of OData endpoints in C# web api. However rather than hard coding the model by creating the EDM from a C# class, I want the endpoints to be dynamic and allow the admin to specify what they want in their model before the api is launched. They can do this by defining a set of "Custom Views" in appSettings.json. And the model is then created at runtime dynamically from the specified settings. Here is an example appSettings.json:

```
 "custom_views": {
    "imdb_view": {
      "sources": [ "imdbtitle" ],
      "fields": {
        "ObjectID": "objectId",
        "URI": "uri",
        "Location": "location",
        "Name": "data.imdbTitle.name",
        "Year": "data.imdbTitle.year",
        "Type": "data.imdbTitle.type",
        "Genres": "data.imdbTitle.genres",
        "CoreContentSize": "coreContentSize"
      },
      "key": "ObjectID"
    },
```

The key in each entry of the "custom_views" dict is the name of the data model and should be the value appended to the url to hit the endpoint. So the endpoint in the example would be hit by visiting: "{url}/Odata/imdb_view" The "sources" is where the elastic indexes to be searched are specified and is not relevant to this question. The fields dict is what is used to create the model. Each key in the dict is the name of an attribute whilst the value is its elastic address which is used to determine the type of that attribute. Finally the "key" specifies which of the fields is the key attribute.

The admin should be able to specify as many custom views as necessary by adding more entries to the "custom_views" dict. For this example a single endpoint should be created based on the data model called "imdb_view" with the attributes:

- ObjectID
- Location
- Name
- Year
- Type
- Genres
- CoreContentSize

I have attempted this and have managed to create an endpoint with the correct data model. However I get a warning in the console and the endpoint acts as a normal REST endpoint rather than an OData endpoint.

Here is how I have attempted this:

In configure services in startup.cs I have created a new OData component and called the GetEDMModel() function.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers(
                options =>
                {
                    options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
                })
                .AddOData(options =>
            {
                options.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Count().SetMaxTop(null);
                options.AddRouteComponents("odata", GetEdmModel());
            });
```

The GetEdmModel() function extracts the data from AppSettings.json and for each custom view, first dynamically creates a CSharp Type at runtime with the correct properties by calling DynamicClassGenerator.CreateDynamicClass(). This is a function I have created which returns a Type with the correct attributes and name. It then adds an EntitySet on the ODataConventionModelBuilder() by calling builder.AddEntityType().

```
private IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
        {
            var customViews = Configuration.GetSection("custom_views").GetChildren()
                .Select(x => new DynamicEntityType
                {
                    Name = x.Key,
                    Key = x.GetValue<string>("key"),
                    Fields = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                })
                .ToList();

            var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

            foreach (var customView in customViews)
            {
                Configuration.GetSection($"custom_views:{customView.Name}:fields").Bind(customView.Fields);
                var dynamicType = DynamicClassGenerator.CreateDynamicClass(customView.Name, customView.Fields);

                var entityType = builder.AddEntityType(dynamicType);

                PropertyInfo key = dynamicType.GetProperty(customView.Key);

                if (key is null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException($"Key specified for {customView.Name} does not exist in the provided fields");
                }




                entityType.HasKey(key);

                builder.AddEntitySet(customView.Name, entityType);

            }

            return builder.GetEdmModel();
```

So the OData endpoint is added correctly with the created EDM. This is working correctly as when I spin up the API and visit the /Odata/$metadata endpoint. I get the following, which is as i expected:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
<edmx:DataServices>
<Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="Default">
<EntityType Name="imdb_view">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="ObjectID"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="ObjectID" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="CoreContentSize" Type="Edm.Int64"/>
<Property Name="Genres" Type="Collection(Edm.String)"/>
<Property Name="Location" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="Type" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="URI" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="Year" Type="Edm.Int64"/>
</EntityType>
<EntityContainer Name="Container">
<EntitySet Name="imdb_view" EntityType="Default.imdb_view"/>
</EntityContainer>
</Schema>
</edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Here is how I have set up my controller:

```
namespace InsightMaker.Middleware.PowerBIConnector.Controllers
{
    [Route("odata/{view_name}")]
    public class CustomViewController : ODataController
    {

        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly ElasticContext _elasticContext;
        public CustomViewController(IConfiguration configuration, ElasticContext elasticContext)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _elasticContext = elasticContext;
        }

        private DynamicEntityType GetViewInfo(string view_name)
        {
            var customViews = _configuration.GetSection("custom_views").GetChildren()
                .Select(x => new DynamicEntityType
                {
                    Name = x.Key,
                    Key = x.GetValue<string>("key"),
                    Sources = x.GetSection("sources").Get<string[]>(),
                    Fields = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                })
                .ToList();
            var activeView = customViews.FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.Name == view_name);
            if (activeView == null) { return null; }

            _configuration.GetSection($"custom_views:{activeView.Name}:fields").Bind(activeView.Fields);

            return activeView;
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<dynamic>> Get(string view_name)
        {
            var activeView = GetViewInfo(view_name);
            if (activeView == null) { return NotFound(); }

            var dynamicType = DynamicClassGenerator.CreateDynamicClass(activeView.Name, activeView.Fields);
            var userName = _configuration.GetValue<string>("loggedInUser");

            var resp = DataMappingService.MapResponseData(dynamicType, _elasticContext, activeView, userName);

            return Ok(resp);
        }
    }
}
```

I have created a controller called CustomViewController, which has a route OData/{custom_view} assigned to it. In this case when the user visits: {url}/Odata/{view name}.

The view_name is passed to the controller and then used to select an active view. The rest of the code in the controller is not relevant to the question and is working as expected. It uses the information about the view to retrieve the data from elastic and returns the data as an Action Result.

Here is the issue:

When starting up the API i get the following Warning in the console:

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Conventions.AttributeRoutingConvention[0]
      The path template 'odata/{view_name}' on the action 'Get' in controller 'CustomView' is not a valid OData path template. Resource not found for the segment '{view_name}'.
```

And when I hit the endpoint by going to `{url}/OData/imdb_view` I get the correct data but It is not formatted as I would expect for an OData endpoint. It is missing things like the @Odata.Context that I would expect to see and there is no mention of OData in the header. The data is simply returned as a JSON as if this was a regular REST endpoint.

I'm really not sure what else to try here and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).